# Add an animation to jQuery scrolling sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a scrolling sidebar function in jQuery and would like to add an animation to the transition.  How do I edit my code to apply an animation to smooth the transition when scrolling up and down on the page?

Here is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cearnhart/4VbDN/5/)

Here is my js:

```
$(function() {

    var $blah   = $("#blah"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $blah.offset();

  $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
   $blah.css('top','120px');
         } else {
   $blah.css('top','440px');
   }
    });


});
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#blah {
    display:none;
    top: 320px;
    right: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.stop().animate()`. The reason why I recommend using `.stop()` before `.animate()` is to prevent the effects from chaining excessively. Basically you're going to instruct the browser to "drop what you're doing now when I scroll" and then "start animation".

```
$(function () {

    var $blah = $("#blah"),
        $window = $(window),
        offset = $blah.offset();

    $window.scroll(function () {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $blah.stop().animate({
                top: 50
            });
        } else {
            $blah.stop().animate({
                top: 100
            });
        }
    });
});
```

See fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/4VbDN/6/

[Edit]: You can even adjust the duration of the animation as well as assign a callback function even `.animation()` is triggered. For more instructions, check the [jQuery API for .animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) :)